# Не получается обработать исключение

Tags: python

Не получается обработать исключение

```
import hypixel

API_KEYS = ['api']
hypixel.setKeys(API_KEYS)

l = -1

f = open('nicknames.txt', 'r')
f1 = open('sorted.txt', 'w', encoding='utf-8')
lines = f.readlines()

for i in open('nicknames.txt', 'r'):
    l += 1
    try:
        Player = hypixel.Player(lines[l].replace('\n', ''))
    except hypixel.PlayerNotFoundException:
        print('No name')
```

Должен выполняться код после except hypixel.PlayerNotFoundException, но выполняется после try и программа кидает ошибку.

```
raise PlayerNotFoundException(uuid)
hypixel.PlayerNotFoundException: noname23003030303
```

Comment: Python 3 или 2? Похоже на 3... А в чём сакральный смысл цикла по _единственному_ файловому дескриптору?

Comment: Цикл тут по строчкам в файле, но, ведь мы их в переменную `lines` уже загрузили. Вероятно ошибка и надо `for i in lines`. К тому надо закрывать файл, либо еще лучше исплоьзовать контекстный менеджер (ключевое слово `with`)